# Cell reference formula within formula to pick out a group of similar rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with 1000+ rows. One column is the Item Name. Each Item Name is unique, but will appear in 8 to 15 rows contiguous of data (before going to the next item name), the number of rows in each dataset can vary.

I need to apply a formula (LINEST, etc) to that only references each Item's set of data. So I need some formula help to make a cell reference that starts at the beginning and ends at the end of the Item's set of data.

I think the solution will be like the helper column created in the post [Colour coding blocks of rows using conditional formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/91121/colour-coding-blocks-of-rows-using-conditional-formatting)

```
Item Name   Data 1  Data 2
10L-101-1   20.0    1.75
10L-101-1   17.5    1.49
10L-101-1   15.0    1.24
10L-101-1   12.5    0.92
10L-101-1   10.0    0.63
10L-101-1   7.5     0.41
10L-101-1   5.0     0.24
10L-101-1   2.5     0.11
10L-101-1   0.0     0.00
10L-102-1   20.0    0.35
10L-102-1   17.5    0.30
10L-102-1   15.0    0.25
10L-102-1   12.5    0.23
10L-102-1   10.0    0.11
10L-102-1   7.5     0.07
10L-102-1   5.0     0.04
10L-102-1   2.5     0.01
10L-103-1   0.0     0.00
10L-103-1   20.0    1.75
10L-103-1   17.5    1.50
10L-103-1   15.0    1.27
10L-103-1   12.5    0.92
10L-103-1   10.0    0.62
10L-103-1   7.5     0.40
10L-103-1   5.0     0.23
10L-103-1   2.5     0.08
10L-103-1   0.0     0.00
```

Comment: Not sure if you need this on a one-time basis, ongoing basis, or if the part numbers are always the same.  If one-time or the part numbers are always the same, you could do an advanced filter > unique values and copy this to another column, then do SUMIF in the adjacent columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INDEX` or `OFFSET` for this - `INDEX` is usually preferable because it's not a "volatile" function like `OFFSET`.

For a specific item name in E2 use this formula to get the column B range of data for that item number

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,E2)-1))`

If you want column C obviously change both B:B refs to C:C and for both columns together change the second B:B only to C:C

The `OFFSET` version:

`=OFFSET(B1,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(A:A,E2))`